# How to write an expression in assembly with no operands?

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to write this expression A = (B × (C + D × (E × F))) ÷ (E × (C + D)) using an instruction set where each instruction has no operands (except for the two that must have one each).

This is an example from the book that I've followed: The expression is z = x * y + w * u

The code:

```
PUSH x
PUSH y
MULT
PUSH w
PUSH u
MULT
ADD
STORE z
```

What I have done:

```
PUSH E
PUSH F
MULT
PUSH D
MULT 
PUSH C
ADD
PUSH B
MULT
STORE Z (store the result)
PUSH C
PUSH D
ADD
PUSH E
MULT
PUSH Z
DIVIDE
STORE A
```

I'm not sure about the way that I stored the result in and the division seems incorrect. Is there a better way to write the expression?

Updated:

```
PUSH C
PUSH D
ADD
PUSH E
MULT
PUSH E
PUSH F
MULT
PUSH D
MULT
PUSH C
ADD
PUSH B
MULT
DIVIDE
STORE A
```

Comment: Is the Updated version correct?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Z`: calculate `Ex(C+D)`, *then* calculate `(B×(C+D×(E×F)))`; now you have the values you need for the final division, which can then be stored in `A`.  In fact, except for avoiding redundant calculations, you should never need to use `STORE` until the very end.

If your division is incorrect (you don't specify what assembly language this is, so I can't tell), then most likely you have the arguments backwards.  In that case, you'd want to leave out the first `STORE Z` and the `PUSH Z`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, is that what you exactly mean?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not able to test my code, the assignment is about how to use"reverse Polish notation (RPN)"

Comment: Then why do you say "the division seems incorrect"?

Comment: I used STORE Z to POP the stack, then I Pushed Z again to do the division and I'm completely not sure about if storing Z means popping from the stack

Comment: Now that you avoid STOREing Z, it isn't a problem!

Comment: I've just got it, there is no need for STOREing Z